# Combining Certbot with an Nginx server block maker

Tags: shell-script, ssl, certbot

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 environment with a pure Nginx server and I use the following Bash script to automate creation of **server blocks** and corresponding (self-signed) **SSL certifications**.

It allows me to create these from anywhere in the CLI, this way:

```
csb domain.tld
```

- [This is the script](https://gist.github.com/benosx/007af35869ff930c7c61930d9aeaf546).
- [This is the script's server block template](https://gist.github.com/benosx/563b403a320d6deffccae4e438244532) that will be rendered to create the site's specific server block and certificate.

Self signed certificates makes surfing impossible (`this connection cannot be trusted` errors appear).

How to replace the part that creates the self-signed corresponding certificates, with a typical CertBot automation script?

<sub>Feel free to fork on Github and start a project if you desire</sub>

Comment: Isn't there a certbot plugin for nginx yet? Or is that just apache?

Comment: Assuming there is, what stages should it save (what can go down from the script)? This is only Nginx.

Comment: From what I've seen, what the apache plugin does is essentially recognize and intercept Let's Encrypt token requests and directs them to where certbot has stored the tokens. I'm not at work right now, but when I get there I'll check the webserver and see if I can give you more detail.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. It's a valid question.

Comment: @Benia I don't understand what you want a moderator to do here.

Comment: I assumed not all mods saw this and mods with enough Nginx experience might want to write their answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as promised in comments I've taken a look at how `dehydrated-apache2` (`dehydrated` is debian's version of the Let's Encrypt script) handles it, and it's actually pretty straightforward. The core of it is a simple redirect alias:

```
AliasMatch /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ /var/lib/dehydrated/acme-challenges/$1
```

This config part is loaded outside of any VirtualHost contexts, so it takes precedence. In order to translate that into your setup you'll need to do two things I can't help you with:

1. find out where your version of certbot stores its challenge tokens. `/var/lib` is usually a safe bet to start looking.
2. Write an `nginx` config file that sets up an alias match linking `/.well-known-acme-challenge/ to that directory on a global basis. I'd recommend the full regular expression to avoid potential directory traversal leakage but that's up to you.

Once you have that, then simply calling `certbot` to create and update SSL certificates will have it generate certificate signing requests, creating the challenge tokens and signalling the Let's Encrypt server, which will then attempt to verify the token before signing the certificate.

I'm likely going to be in your shoes at some point, except in my case I'll be editing a full-blown perl script I wrote years ago, so when I say 'good luck' I'm not being deliberately mocking...

**EDIT** You'll also want to modify your block template to include the directories used by certbot; this will likely be easier for you than adding postrun hooks to certbot to copy the certs over to your nginx SSL directory.

**SECOND EDIT** According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360744/how-to-replace-the-apache-aliasmatch-function-in-nginx), the `nginx` equivalent code would be approximately

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ {
    alias /var/lib/dehydrated/acme-challenges/$1;
}
```

but I'll leave that to you to work out and test.

Comment: I mentioned apache because that's where I have a working example. And yes, I'm suggesting that you implement the same functionality in nginx -- I'm pretty sure it can do that, it's just that I don't use nginx much so I haven't the faintest how.

Comment: Code example for what? Like I said, I have zero experience with `nginx` or how it handles aliases.

Comment: For the `bash` script? just swap out the generate_certs() function for a call to whatever distribution you're working from wraps around `certbot` for ease of use. Too many unknowns for me to even make a guess.

Comment: I *think* Ubuntu uses `dehydrated` same as debian - they do tend to borrow everything they can from Debian - in which case you just need to add the new site's name as a new line in `/var/lib/dehydrated/domains.txt` and call `dehydrated --cron` for an immediate update.